# Create folder inside a bucket in minio using JAVA SDK

Tags: minio

The Minio JAVA SDK documentation doesn't clearly articulate how to create a folder inside a bucket.

Can somebody help me on this request ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 9):

In the objectName parameter prefix of the putObject method, you can specify a folder name.
https://docs.minio.io/docs/java-client-api-reference#putObject
https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/2423#issuecomment-239408168

For example:

```
//objectName = folderName + "/" + fileName;
minioClient.putObject(bucketName, objectName, inputStream, contentType);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the bucket if its not present.
To add folder within it add it to the name of file.
Eg. File name: "sample.txt", Bucket Name: "main", SubFolder: "resrc"
filePath: file which you want to upload

**minioClient.putObject("main", "resrc" + "/" + "sample.txt", filePath);**

Answer (score 1):

Create or check for exist.

```
// Create object ends with '/' (also called as folder or directory).
minioClient.putObject(
PutObjectArgs.builder().bucket("my-bucketname").object("path/to/").stream(
new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {}), 0, -1).build());
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).